# SQL Sum of each character in a number

Tags: sql, function, math, addition

I want to sum each character of an integer in SQL

For instance. I have `16273481 as INT`

But now (Without to complicated methods) sum

```
1 + 6 + 2 + 7 + 3 + 4 + 8 + 1 = 32
```

Comment: There are plenty of solutions that are easily found via Google.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://www.goo.gl/8oUc1C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @someInt INT = 16273481


-- you could put this all into a function
-- and then it would be reusable...
-- 
-- like... SELECT SumOfIndividualIntegers(16273481)

DECLARE @count INT = LEN(@someInt),
        @counter INT = 1

DECLARE @Sum INT = 0

WHILE @counter <= @count
BEGIN
    SELECT @sum += CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(@someInt AS VARCHAR), @counter, 1) AS int)
    SELECT @counter += 1
END

SELECT @sum --32
-- and then you would RETURN @sum instead
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought there would have been an easier way like Split, or substring convert to int sum, something in those lines, but this seems to be the best and cleanest way.

Answer (score 2):

Would using the remainder operator be suitable for your situation with a loop?

Pseuodo code:

x = 16273481;
sum = 0;

Loop:
sum = sum + (x % 10);
x = (x / 10);

Something along those lines?